# Why is <form> breaking js function?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, bootstrap-4

I have a page for users to create new accounts. There are only 4 input fields for first and last name, email and password, so instead of using a form and a submit button I'm using ajax to post the input field values to a php file.

One of the buttons on the page is to toggle the visibility of the password input. The button has an onclick event which calls a function called togglepassvis that changes the input type from password to text. All of this is working fine using this method of submitting the input fields via ajax.

I noticed that while I'm working on localhost, Chrome doesn't ask to save the password, even though the password input field is using autocomplete="new-password", so I did some searching and found this Google Developers post. https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/security/credential-management/save-forms

After reading, I added form opening and closing tags to the create account page and got it all working without ajax, using a submit button instead.

But if the button to call "togglepassvis" is inside of the opening and closing form tags, the function no longer works and I get a function togglepassvis not defined error in the console. If I comment out the form opening and closing tags, or move the toggle button outside of them, the function works. Nothing else on the page breaks with the form tags in place, just this single button to toggle the password visibility. Why would the form tags break this function?

```
  <form action='./' method='post'>
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name='password' placeholder="Pass Phrase (Min 16 characters)" minlength="16" required onkeyup="passlength(this.value);" autocomplete="new-password" >
        <div class="input-group-append">
          <button id="togglepassvis" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" name="togglepassvis" onclick="togglepassvis();">Show</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </form>


<script>
function togglepassvis() {
  var pass = document.getElementById("password");
  if (pass.type === "password") {
    pass.type = "text";
    $('#togglepassvis').html("Hide");
  } else {
    pass.type = "password";
    $('#togglepassvis').html("Show");
  }
}
</script>
```

I expected the button and function to toggle the password visibility/change the input type to work the same regardless of the form tags but it doesn't. Instead the togglepassvis function only works if the button calling this function is not within the opening and closing form tags. If the button is within the opening and closing form tags I get the error - 
"Uncaught TypeError: togglepassvis is not a function
    at HTMLButtonElement.onclick"

Comment: ...it's because your button has an ID of `togglepassvis` which is also the name of the function. It's weird but basically all IDs from HTML elements get attached to the `window` object. Since the `togglepassvis` function is global, it also exists on the `window` object and one overwrites the other.

Comment: in reference to above, one fix is to `onclick="window.togglepassvis();"` - which makes me wonder about the accuracy of "one overwrites the other" :p I think it's an oddity with the context of `onclick=`

Comment: @JaromandaX *damn*. Yeah, now that you mention it - there was something about `onclick` in the HTML and its context. I can't remember exactly and I can't find it now, but I seem to recall it's actually doing something akin to using `with` - it was probably stacking scope chains in some slightly unintuitive way but you could specify `window` to directly address a global property. Also, I now noticed that I forgot a rather crucial specification in my previous comment it should start with "...it's **most likely**".

Comment: Using inline onClick handlers is a bad idea in general, especially since you're using jQuery. `$("#togglepassvis").on("click", togglepassvis)` is both cleaner *and* you don't need to worry about strange edge cases.

Comment: Thanks for all of your suggestions. Both of the solutions are working in my application if either/both of you would like to post an answer.

Comment: I think the jquery answer is cleaner (you can do it without jquery too, i.e. getElementById and addEventListner) - I'd write an answer, but I don't have a good explanation for the reason - more research required :p

Comment: I agree, I went with the jquery solution @JJJ provided because it separates the html and js code. I'm learning a lot about js/jquery this week, I've mostly programmed in PHP so far but jquery is fun except for the syntax.